# Automated tests with Doze mode on android

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-doze

I am trying to write some automated tests for how my app functions when the device enters and exits Doze mode. I know that you can use `dumpsys deviceidle force-idle` to force the device into idle mode when doing manual testing.

Is there a way to run that command from within a test app, or (better yet) an Android API to request Doze mode? If there isn't, does anyone have a recommendation for documentation regarding a good way to run `adb` commands at fixed points in an integration test?